# c# browse for a image on web applications and display it

Tags: c#, asp.net

What would be the best way to create a C# Web Application that allows the user to browse for an image and then display it? 
An equivalent of Picturebox in windows applications, sort of

Ideally the user should be able to click on Browse, choose the picture and see it in the browser itself

Thanks

Comment: So you understand that the user will need to upload the image to the server for the server to display it back to the user right? Why do you need to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are all ready some image-browser for asp.net including source code.

Some of them

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17605/Thumbnail-Image-Viewer-Control-for-ASP-NET-2-0

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29846/A-simple-ASP-NET-AJAX-image-browser

Answer (score 1):

For this, the user needs to choose an image which will be uploaded to the server, and then rendered in the HTML or recovered using AJAX. The problem is that you can't get rid of the send/receive, and it can get slow.

You can use a `FileUpload` or any other component that allows to upload files directly or via AJAX (look at [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) AjaxControlToolkit for this).

Then you need to add an `<img>` to your page, through a full postback or using any other means (like jQuery.Ajax).